# Описание функции strcmpi() в си

Tags: c, строки

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать о работе функции strcmpi() в си, а именно как получить результат сравнения двух строк независимо от регистра. В качестве примера приведу следующий код:

```
int  k=0, res=0;
char a[5];
    char b[5];
    scanf("%s\n", &a);
    scanf("%s\n", &b);
    res = _strcmpi(a, b);
    if (res > 0)
        {k++;}
    printf("%d", k);
```

Цель: если строки a и b равны то значение k должно быть 1, но в данном случае это не срабатывает. Хотелось бы узнать ошибку? заранее спасибо.

Comment: А какие слова вводите? Далеко не все реализации умеют работать с русскими буквами, например... Вы точно вводите не более 4 букв? Проверьте заодно работу, не вводя строки, а присваивая их в коде.

Comment: Ввожу три буквы:abs или Abs или abS( независимо от регистра) но k=0 остается...         Если  ввожу вначале char a[5]="abs";
 char b[5]="abS"; то результат тот же

Comment: Ну так все правильно, функция сравнения [дает 0, если строки равны, значение меньше нуля или больше в зависимости от того, какая из строк лексикографически меньше](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)... https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/ru_RU/strcmpi.html

Comment: т.е исправляем на if(res==0)? Ок, спасибо

Comment: Исправляйте :))

Comment: Я только не понял, а зачем Вы используете некое чудо под названием *_strcmpi* вместно нормального вызова *strcasecmp* ? Читаем *man 3 strcasecmp* : The strcasecmp() function performs a byte-by-byte comparison of the strings s1 and s2, ignoring the case of the characters.  It returns an integer less  than,  equal to,  or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Comment: Чтение документации? Не, не слышал...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да начнётся битва VS против K&R, POSIX vs BSD, man vs MSDN... :-)